# Devise and cancan gems: has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan, has-many

I use `devise` and `cancan` gems and have simple model association: `user` `has_many subscriptions`, `subscription` `belongs_to :user`. Have following `SubscriptionsController`:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :subscription, through: :user

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @subscriptions = @user.subscriptions.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order(:created_at)
  end

  #other actions
end
```

And `Cancan` `Ability.rb`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||=User.new

    can [:read], [Edition, Kind]

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.id
      can [:read, :create, :destroy, :pay], Subscription, user_id: user.id
      can [:delete_from_cart, :add_to_cart, :cart], User, id: user.id
    end

  end

end
```

The problem is that i cannot use `subscriptions` actions as a user but can as a admin. And have no problems with `UsersController`. When i delete following lines from `SubscriptionsController`:

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :subscription, through: :user

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Have no problems at all. So the issue in these lines or in `Ability.rb`. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** It's interesting that if i add smth like `can? :index, Subscription` to html template it displays `true`. If add smth like `can? :index, Subscription.first` (subscription of another user) it shows `false`. Looks like `Cancan` works normally. But what's the problem?..

**UPDATE**: If change `SubscriptionsControlle` like:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  #load_and_authorize_resource :user
  #load_and_authorize_resource :subscription, through: :user

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find params[:user_id] #line 1
    @subscription = @user.subscriptions.find params[:id] #line 2
    @container_items = @subscription.container_items.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    authorize! :show, @subscription #line 4
  end

  #some actions
end
```

It works perfect and prevent unauthorized user access when need.
Are the lines #1, 2 and 4 not equivalent to commented?..

**UPDATE**: Have the following in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users, except: [:show] do
    member do
      get 'cart'
      delete 'delete_from_cart' => 'users#delete_from_cart'
      post 'add_to_cart' => 'users#add_to_cart'
    end
    resources :subscriptions do
      member do
        post 'pay'
      end
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE**: Next solution prevent unauthorized access to all of subscriptions actions except `index`:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  load_resource :user
  load_resource :subscription, through: :user
  authorize_resource through: :current_user

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  #actions
end
```

So what's the best way to prevent access to `index` action?

Found only following solution:

```
  before_filter :authorize_index, only: [:index]

  def authorize_index
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless params[:user_id] == current_user.id.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
load_and_authorize_resource :subscription
```

or just

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

in your case, when you want nested resource, then

```
load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_user
```

see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources

Comment: So i can see there: `class TasksController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :task, :through => :project
end`. And what is the difference?

Comment: How do you expect the "load_and_authorize_resource :user" to work? What should it authorize the user instance with?

Comment: I have following in my `routes.rb`: `resources :users, except: [:show] do
    resources :subscriptions do
      member do
        post 'pay'
      end
    end
  end`

Comment: It means have a `:user_id` in url.

Comment: Yes, but I repeat - authorize it with what? You probably need to have instead: load_resource :user

Comment: Thank very much, it works! But now i have an ability to see subscriptions of another users. How to prevent it? Have the following in `SubscriptionsController`: `load_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :subscription, through: :user
  before_filter :authenticate_user!` . May be redefine `authenticate_user!` method?

Comment: Yes, I suggest that you use devise gem, and then only load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_user

Comment: If leave only : `load_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource through: :current_user

  before_filter :authenticate_user!`. It doesn't prevent anything.

Comment: As I said, I suggest that you have an authentication in place, such as devise, and then you just need "load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_user", that's it.